# Do Office Add-ins require a framework like Angular?

Tags: office-js

I want to start building an Office add-in which could grow in size and was wondering if I should use a JavaScript framework or not.
Most of the examples on the Office Dev website use jQuery (for demonstration purposes I suppose) and on GitHub there are some projects which use Angular 1 or 2.

In this book 'Building Office Add-ins using Office.js' I read that Typescript would not be a bad choice as the language for writing add-ins.
So I was wondering if Angular 4 which is all Typescript would be a good start for building an add-in?

The reason I ask also got to do with it's size. It's a huge framework with a lot of scaffolding and might it not be overkill.
I can also imagine that the platform one is creating an add-in for would play a role. (PC or OfficeOnline)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do Office Add-ins require a framework like Angular?

No, the Office Add-in doesn't require **ANY** 3rd party framework (other than Office.js framework itself). You probably should start your discovery from reading the following resource: [Anatomy of an Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#anatomy-of-an-office-add-in).

To make story short your add-in description is the manifest file, which will be distributed to your customers; your add-in content is the website (web application). What ever technology your hosted environment for your website supports use them or if you able to add to this hosted environment, technologies you picked, you may use them as well. For example application planned to be hosted on your own IIS Webserver, in this case you free to use, but not limited, aspx pages (C#, VB.Net, etc.) as server side technology, JS and any JS frameworks you are able to install into your webserver. If Hosted environment is not hosted by your company, check out if they support the technology you picked.

Comment: This is the first I've heard that a server-side only framework like ASP.NET can be used for the UI, otherwise what is there other than JavaScript API for Office?? If this is true, I'm really going to bang my head against the desk. Unless you mean how your client-side code can communicate with your back-end server running whatever

Comment: @Slava Many thanks for your comment and sorry for being so vague.
I did not get across that my real question was if Angular 4 wasn't to big a framework for using in Word Online for example. In Word Online the add-in is being run in a iframe if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @EricLegault I am sorry, may be I wasn't clear, but Office,js is the requirement just because we are talking about Office Add-in, how else we can communicate with the Office communication. I though this is definition, when discussing Office Add-in. When I said, not require any framework, I meant 3rd party framework. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @DutchDan Any framework you are going to use will be cached by the browser as we run app in iframe, right? Why would the size of Angular framework is concern, but for example JQuery is not? I like the idea of the minimal usage of frameworks, but it's all depend on your requirements. For example our app uses JQuery and Office FabricUI, nothing else. This was the choice according our app requirement.

Comment: Angular 4 definitely does work inside of Office Add-ins -- in fact, we have a large sample we'll be publishing soon that makes very good use of it!  By the way, we can also generate an Angular project using the `yeoman` generator (https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office), though last I checked, the version of Angular that the generator outputs is still Angular 1 (but you're welcome to submit a pull request :-) )

Comment: @Michael Very much looking forward to that large Angular 4 sample!

Comment: See Script Lab (newly announced getting-started/prototyping tool), at https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab.  We also had a recent podcast talking about it: https://blogs.office.com/2017/04/20/episode-127-new-script-lab-office-add-michael-zlatkovsky-bhargav-krishna-office-365-developer-podcast/